# R: how many equal letters between two strings

Tags: r

I have 2 strings: "aaaabbC" and "adgfccc"

I want to know how many letters appear both in the first and second string (and not how many times a letter apears)

in my example, the answer will be: 2 (because of a and c).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to stochazesthai's response, you can use `unique()`:

```
length(unique(as.vector(unlist(strsplit(x,"")),mode="list")))
length(unique(as.vector(unlist(strsplit(y,"")),mode="list")))
```

This should help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pmatch`:

```
x = "aaaabbc"
y = "adgfccc"

a = unlist(strsplit(x,""))
b = unlist(strsplit(y,""))

sum(!is.na(pmatch(a,b)))
```

Type `?pmatch` to see further details.